# Boys find hollow meteorite in Scottish countryside

Tags: story-identification, movie

I'm trying to find a movie that opens with two boys that find a large hollow meteorite in what I believe is the Scottish countryside. A neighbor man comes to help them break into it... and that's the last part of the show I remember.
I think it's a fairly (last 10 years) recent movie.
Any thoughts?
Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to SciFi.SE. Could you clarify if the movie contained any science-fictional or fantastical elements?

Comment: If the correct answer is posted, you can accept by clicking on the checkmark by the voting buttons, as per the [tour].

Comment: I'm sorry, Fez, that's all that I can remember.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

If that would be a post-credit scene and not an opening one, it could be the [very ending](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JWTxn077nOU) of a movie [Battleship (2012)](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt1440129/).
[Article + screenshot](https://screenrant.com/battleship-credits-scene-explained/#:%7E:text=Battleship%27s%20post%2Dcredits%20scene%20unfolds,them%20fleeing%20away%20in%20fear.)

[image: Image showing the boys finding the meteorite]

> Battleship's post-credits scene unfolds in Scotland, where three teenagers come across a mysterious cubical structure that seems to have fallen from the sky. When an adult joins them and budges the object open, a pair of alien arms spring out of it and sends them fleeing away in fear...

Comment: Yeah, I immediately thought of the end of Battleship as well

Comment: Oh my gosh!!  That is totally it!!  You all are Brilliant!! No wonder I couldn't remember anything else about the movie... there Was No movie!!  Just (apparently) a set up for a sequel, right?  Well done!!   My OCD-ness was going nuts over this, and I couldn't just "let it go"!!  Thank you, Thank you!!